# Insertt value to database from GridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, gridview

I am trying get value from GridView and decrement it that works. However, inserting to the database does not work. What's wrong?

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    m = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text;
    int nm = Convert.ToInt32(m);
    if (GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text != "")
    {
        cn.Open();
        nm--;
        cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO rezerwacje [miejsca] VALUES(@nm)");
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Clone();
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Check if miejsca is an IDENTITY column.

Comment: Nothing save in DB. /miejsca/ is not a datakeys of gridview, because datakeys is use in another place. Can i insert /miejsca/ when it' not a datakey? how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are not adding the parameter value

```
cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO rezerwacje [miejsca] VALUES(@nm)");
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("nm", nm));
```